# How can I start my NestJs application on amazon EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, nestjs, typeorm, npm-start

I'am trying to deploy my NestJs application on an EC2 instance.
I cloned my project and installed all dependencies but then when I tried to start the app, it can't initialize all dependencies (can't even reach TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies).
I have no errors.

```
[Nest] 117257   - 09/27/2021, 1:14 AM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 117257   - 09/27/2021, 1:14 AM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +176ms
[Nest] 117257   - 09/27/2021, 1:14 AM   [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 117257   - 09/27/2021, 1:14 AM   [InstanceLoader] NeconfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 117257   - 09/27/2021, 1:14 AM   [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 117257   - 09/27/2021, 1:14 AM   [InstanceLoader] CommentsModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 117257   - 09/27/2021, 1:14 AM   [InstanceLoader] MsPostsModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 117257   - 09/27/2021, 1:14 AM   [InstanceLoader] PostCommentsModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 117257   - 09/27/2021, 1:14 AM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 117257   - 09/27/2021, 1:14 AM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +11ms
[Nest] 117257   - 09/27/2021, 1:14 AM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +1ms
```

I my local machine the Nest application is successfully started.

```
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +112ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] NeconfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] CommentsModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] MsPostsModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] PostCommentsModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +236ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] NotificationModule dependencies initialized +16ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] PostContentModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] FollowersTsModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] FavorisModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] PostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] AccountModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [InstanceLoader] UsersModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +8ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/facebook, GET} route +3ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/facebook/redirect, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/authorize_user, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/handleauth, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/handleauthcode, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/google, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/google/redirect, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RoutesResolver] UsersController {/users}: +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/createUser, POST} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/:id, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/search/:email, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/:id, PUT} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/:id, DELETE} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/login, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/confirm/:id, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/resetPassword, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/changePassword/:id, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/follow, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/unfollow, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/inst, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/googlelogin, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/facebooklogin, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/testTypeCnx/:id, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RoutesResolver] NotificationController {/notification}: +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/addNotif, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getNotif, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RoutesResolver] CommentsController {/comments}: +0ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RoutesResolver] MsPostsController {/ms-posts}: +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RoutesResolver] AccountController {/account}: +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/createOneAccount, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getAllUser, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getUserByName/:userName, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/UpdateUser/:userName, PUT} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/DeleteByUsername/:userName, DELETE} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/addFromxlsx, POST} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/showAllUsername, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getBestAccountLastMonth, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getBestAccountLastYear, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getRankAccountLastWeek, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getBestAccountByDay, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getRank/:starName/:dateTest, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getFollowersByDay/:userName, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getFollowersByMonth/:starName, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getFollowersByweek/:starName, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/compare/:starName1/:starName2, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/createData/:starName/:fieldScrape/:countryScrape, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RoutesResolver] PostController {/post}: +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/allPosts, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/country, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/username/:userName/:skip, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/Rankingpermonth/:month/:year/:skip, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/:userName/Rankingpermonth/:month/:year/:skip, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/maxMonth, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/avgLikesMonth, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/avgCommentMonth, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/RankingLastweek/:skip, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/:userName/RankingLastweek/:skip, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/Rankingperyear/:year/:skip, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/:userName/Rankingperyear/:year/:skip, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/totalYear, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/maxYear, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/likesYear/:year/:skip, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/likesMonth/:year/:month/:skip, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/likesAllTimes/:skip, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/celeblikesAllTimes/:userName/:skip, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/celeblikesByMonth/:userName/:year/:month, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/celeblikesByYear/:userName/:year/:skip, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/avgCommentYear, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/maxCommentYear, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RoutesResolver] PostContentController {/postContent}: +0ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/postId, GET} route +3ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RoutesResolver] PostCommentsController {/post-comments}: +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RoutesResolver] FavorisController {/favoris}: +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/addFavoris/:idUser, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getAllFavoris/:idUser, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/addFavorisToAccount/:idUser/:starName, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/checkFavorit/:idUser/:starName, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/FavorisByYear/:idUser, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/FavorisByMonth/:idUser, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/FavorisByDay/:idUser, GET} route +3ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/fovorisAll/:idUser, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/deleteFavoris/:idUser/:starName, DELETE} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/FavorisByWeek/:idUser, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RoutesResolver] FollowersTsController {/followers-ts}: +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/insertDataToDataBase/:username, POST} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getAllData/:starName, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getDataofSpecificDate/:starName, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getAccountLastYear, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getAccountLastMonth, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/getAccountLastWeek, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/scrappingInsta/:starName/:fieldScrape/:countryScrape, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 15660   - 27/09/2021, 03:10:58   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +9ms
```

And this is my main.ts file

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import * as http from 'http';
import * as express from 'express';
const fs = require('fs');

dotenv.config();
async function bootstrap() {
 
  const server = express();
  const app = await NestFactory.create(
    AppModule,
  );
  app.enableCors({
    "origin": "*",
    "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    "preflightContinue": false,
    "allowedHeaders" : ['Content-Type']
  });
  await app.init();
  http.createServer(server).listen(3005);
}
bootstrap();
```

I can't figure out why the app can't be started successfully in the ec2 instance.

Comment: I didn't understand why you are using `express` (and `http`) directly if you are using Nestjs. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Excuse me but they are not the source of my problem, they change nothing.

Comment: Usually when this happens there's a dynamic module returning `undefined`, a `circular dependency` that's not resolving properly (even for Nest's error), or a module throwing an error that is somehow getting swallowed. Verify all your configs are correct and that there are no circular dependencies (`madge` is a good tool for that)